# Where do I go in my app to change framework ver to match what's installed

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

Getting the following .Net message in my blazor server app. Where do I go in my app to change the framework to match what I already have installed?

```
You must install or update .NET to run this application.

    App: C:\apps\BlazorApp1.exe
    Architecture: x64
    Framework: 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '6.0.23' (x64)
    .NET location: C:\Program Files\dotnet\
    
    The following frameworks were found:
      6.0.22 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
      7.0.11 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

And it shows I have 6.0.23 in control panel

[image]

Comment: Have you updated some of the packages in your application?

Comment: This is a brand new project blazor server side template from scratch and i just started the app and got the message

Comment: On the assumption you're using VS, what version?